# Plotly line graph to follow ordered time series on X-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
country = ['Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Lao PDR',
 'Lao PDR',
 'Lao PDR',
 'Lao PDR']

month_year = ['2020-Aug',
 '2020-Dec',
 '2020-May',
 '2020-Oct',
 '2021-Mar',
 '2020-Jul',
 '2021-Mar',
 '2021-May',
 '2021-Nov']

count = [5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6]

# Make dictionary, keys will become dataframe column names
intermediate_dictionary = {'country':country, 'month_year':month_year, 'count':count}

# Convert dictionary to Pandas dataframe
df3 = pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(intermediate_dictionary)
df3
```

Using the dataframe I ordered the months correctly then plotted a line graph this way

```
ordered_months = ["2020-May", "2020-Jul", "2020-Aug", "2020-Oct", "2020-Dec", "2021-Mar",
      "2021-May", "2021-Nov"]

fig = px.line(df3, x="month_year", y="count", color='country', symbol='country')
fig.update_xaxes( categoryarray= ordered_months)

fig.show()
```

Now my problem is, the line chart for the country cambodia is not following the order of months as expected. Here is a photo of the graph

[image]

According to the graph , cambodia line chart starts from *May-2020* then skips *Aug-2020* and goes to *oct-2020* then go to *Dec-2020* before coming back to *Aug-2020*. Notice also that the line connecting to *Mar-2021* doesnt start from *Dec-2020* but *Oct-2020*.

My intention is the line for cambodia to follow the order of x-axis, from *May-2020* go to *Aug-2020* then *Oct-2020* then *Dec-2020* and finally *Mar-2020*.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: From the data you have shown, the following code will realize the creation of the graph,  `fig = px.line(df3, x="month_year", y="count", color='country', symbol='country')` but where is the `indicator_description` in the y-axis values?

Comment: @r-beginners Apologies, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to solve your problem.

First of all, you create the DF and values, thats Ok. **What I added is the function pd.to_datetime** to make pandas recognise the dates and order them.

```
country = ['Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Cambodia',
 'Lao PDR',
 'Lao PDR',
 'Lao PDR',
 'Lao PDR']

month_year = ['2020-Aug',
 '2020-Dec',
 '2020-May',
 '2020-Oct',
 '2021-Mar',
 '2020-Jul',
 '2021-Mar',
 '2021-May',
 '2021-Nov']

month_year = pd.to_datetime(month_year)
count = [5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6]
```

Then you create the DF, in my case **I sorted by 'month_year'**:

```
# Make dictionary, keys will become dataframe column names
intermediate_dictionary = {'country':country, 'month_year':month_year, 'count':count}

# Convert dictionary to Pandas dataframe
df3 = pd.DataFrame(intermediate_dictionary).sort_values(by='month_year')
```

Finally, plot the graph:

```
fig = px.line(df3, x="month_year", y="count", color='country',symbol='country')
fig.show()
```

The output would be:

[image: output]